# two-way connection between SharePoint list and wiki page?

Tags: list, custom-list, wiki

I received an unusual request and I'm trying to figure out if it's possible:

- store data in a custom list to be used for a report
- output the formatted data to page
- let users edit the page
- page must have "track changes" or "page history" functionality
- (here's the kicker) edits made to the page should automatically appear in the list items

I think that I could write a custom program that would output the list data to a wiki page. However, if changes were made to the wiki page, they wouldn't be reflected in the original list.

Can this be done, and if so, how?

Comment: Why don't you create a Visual Web Part? You can show formatted data from list in the VWP, edits done on the VWP can be directly hit to the Custom list. You can embed the VWP in a Web Part Page.

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri Thanks, I like that idea, but they really want the "track changes"/"page history" functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user really want to go this route.
You need to use an event receiver associated with the pages library.
On item updated you should parse the page html.

Another option is to edit wiki page layout and add a data sheet (but in this case the data will be tabular)

Comment: Thanks, I think this is correct. Parsing the page HTML sounds time-consuming, so maybe they will change their minds based on that.